# adding app setting in android default settings

Tags: android, default, setting

I am developing an app using shared preference and I'm using res/xml/preference.xml for my preferences.

It works fine But now I want these preference to be in the Android Default settings screen 
(Application Manager, Wireless and networks,Call Settings,Sound,Applications etc.. )..

For example the default settings looks like the below.

- Wireless and networks

  1. Wi-Fi
  2. Bluetooth
  3. Mobile Networks
- Device

  1. Sound
  2. Display
  3. Storage

Is it possible to add my own application settings here say for example

- Wireless and networks

  1. Wi-Fi
  2. Bluetooth
  3. Mobile Networks
- Device

  1. Sound
  2. Display
  3. Storage
  4. MyAppSetting  ..........

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to do it on Android.  To be honest I can't see why you would want this as the preferences for the application only need to available when the application is running.

Changing the system preferences would require you to rebuild the ROM from source and I don't think you want your users to have to run a custom ROM just to use your app.